# jquery: realtime messaging from server?

Tags: jquery, python, flask, real-time, messaging

is there a jquery library that can receive notifications from the server? For example, a background task is running on the server, during the processing, I would like the server to "push" a message to the client browser when certain events occur on the server.

I can also use ajax polling to see if a new message has arrived. I'm wondering if there's another way.

Comment: You're probably looking for something along the lines of [Server-Sent Events (SSE)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server-sent_events). What sort of server side framework are you using?

Comment: I am using flask. would having a messaging queuing system help in this case?

Comment: Why not [SignalR](http://signalr.net/)?

Comment: @thepirat000 I don't know how to use .NET. I am using python flask

Comment: who would close this question? I really don't get the logic of the mods here sometimes

Comment: I haven't used but this utility lib - http://thejacklawson.com/Mediator.js/ mentions that it can be used for those purpose on documentation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**UPDATE:** Since I first wrote this, `Portal` reached end-of-life, as pointed out by the author in the comments below. The next suggested library is [Vibe](http://vibe-project.github.io/).

### Using `Vibe`:

Here are instructions to migrate away from `Portal`:

- http://vibe-project.github.io/blog/migration-from-portal/

Here is a quick-start guide for using `Vibe`:

- http://vibe-project.github.io/projects/vibe-javascript-client/3.0.0-Alpha1/#quick-start

---

**Portal.js:** https://github.com/flowersinthesand/portal

This handles many forms of server connection, and is cross browser compatible.

Here is an overall explanation of the library: http://flowersinthesand.github.io/portal/

Here's how to get started: http://flowersinthesand.github.io/portal/documentation/1.1.1/getting-started/

*Library choices are a matter of opinion.* This library has been really awesome to use for me. It actually does not require jQuery, and it is under 9k in size.

---

Here are more, which do depend on jQuery:

- https://code.google.com/p/jquery-websocket/
- https://jwebsocket.org/

**Google search:** https://www.google.com/search?q=websocket+jquery+plugins

Comment: yes this is what I am looking for, is there any other libraries?

Comment: That's all you need. It supports many forms of server-side data. It wraps the standard browser WebSocket connections and other kinds of polling so it is extremely easy for you.

Comment: Hi, I'm the author of Portal. For your information, there was a discussion about using Portal in Python lately. See https://groups.google.com/d/msg/portal_project/Ufj6rNNz3wM/Wi6sDXEkvk8J @digitalextremist Thanks for the recommendation!

Comment: @DonghwanKim thanks for chiming in. Loving Portal.

Comment: @digitalextremist Portal has reached its [End of Life](http://flowersinthesand.github.io/portal/news/2014/10/02/portal-end-of-life/) and is no longer maintained! Use [Vibe](http://vibe-project.github.io/).

Comment: @DonghwanKim thank you for the heads up, I updated my answer and will now update my applications. Need any contributors on Vibe? In particular the JavaScript client? I forked the library and will become familiar with it. I am about to return to WebSocket-heavy code in the near future, so I can possibly help with Vibe.

Comment: @digitalextremist thanks for your consideration. First of all, now active discussion and feedback are needed on [3.0.0-Alpha1 and roadmap](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/atmosphere-framework/Q30YyHJcpCI/AxvSqZ1ehhAJ).

Comment: @digitalextremist I'm sorry to bother you again :) Vibe has been [renamed](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/vibe-project/kmURxoLC85I/UO7ECEdOYs4J) to Cettia and is no longer maintained! Use [Cettia](http://cettia.io/).

Comment: @DonghwanKim, is the name of the library going to stay the same for a while? If so, I can eventually help with it.

Comment: @digitalextremist Yes it is. Thanks for watching Cettia.